# Not getting query results back

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

My query does not return any values even though the table has the records. I am trying to retrieve an employeed id based on the name entered. I keep getting the message "No employee id". I am a new learner as far as Access VBA is concerned. I have worked with Access tables and other tables without issues. I did validate that the form field has the correct value and is being captured in the variable *strEmpName*

```
    Set cnn1 = New ADODB.Connection
    mydb = "C:\accesssamp\Documents\Tasks.accdb"
    strCnn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & mydb
    cnn1.Open strCnn

    'This statement added here just to indicate that I am getting the value
    strEmpName = cboEmployeeName.Text ' Getting employee name from form field

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
        .CommandText = "SELECT [EmployeeId] FROM [Employees] " & _
                        "WHERE [EmployeeName] = [strEmpName]"
        .CommandType = adCmdUnknown
        .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter( _
                    "[strEmpName]", adChar, adParamInput, 50)
        .Parameters("[strEmpName]") = strEmpName
    End With

    ' Execute the Query and return the employeeId
    Set rstEmp = cmd.Execute

    If rstEmp.RecordCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox "No Employee Id"
    Else
        MsgBox rstEmp(0).Value
    End If
```

Comment: What did `Debug.Print` tell you?

Comment: @PaulFrancis Where do I add that statement? I stepped through the code and got the message box "No employee id"

Comment: RecordCount  can be a little odd with ADO, step though and use the immediate window to get `rstEmp(0).Value`. Why are you using ADO with MS Access, rather than DAO? DAO is preferred.

Comment: BTW, from the above, `.CommandType = adCmdText`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample had multiple issues.  I'm unsure whether this is exactly what you want, but it works without error on my system.

```vb
With cmd
    '.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    .ActiveConnection = cnn1
    .CommandText = "SELECT [EmployeeId] FROM [Employees] " & _
                    "WHERE [EmployeeName] = [strEmpName]"
    .CommandType = adCmdUnknown ' or adCmdText; either works
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter( _
                "strEmpName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, strEmpName)
End With

' Execute the Query and return the employeeId
Set rstEmp = cmd.Execute

'If rstEmp.RecordCount < 1 Then
If rstEmp.BOF And rstEmp.EOF Then
    MsgBox "No Employee Id"
Else
    MsgBox rstEmp(0).value
End If
```

Notes:

1. I assumed you want to run your query from the *cnn1* connection to that other database instead of from `CurrentProject.Connection`.
2. Supply a compatible data type for `CreateParameter`.  And for a text parameter, supply a value for its maximum length.  Finally include the value for the parameter.
3. `rstEmp.RecordCount` was returning -1, which is less than 1, so your code displayed *"No Employee Id"* even when the recordset was not empty. Instead of checking `RecordCount`, check whether the recordset is empty.

Comment: It looks like the other thing you did but didn't mention (and I forget if this really matters but) you changed the parameter name from `[strEmpName]` to `strEmpName` when creating the parameter.

Comment: Yes, I did that, but it doesn't matter.  With ADO, the parameter name is completely ignored.

Comment: ah right right, only order matters. I just always name then but I guess I always put them in order so I forget, too. Thanks!